# Cambiar propiedad de Header en control "Expand"

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

Intento cambiar la propiedad `Header` de un Expander para ir variando el titulo de este en funcion de variables pero no hay manera...

Si al Header le pongo una constante funciona correctamente;

```
<Expander Name="Header" Margin="4" Header="Config nivel 0"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el momento que realizo un Binding a una variable en la parte del C# de ja de funcionar y el campo sale vacio...

```
<Expander Name="Header" Margin="4" Header="{Binding Path=header}"/>
```

Y aqui la parte del C# donde hago el binding...

```
    public partial class ConfigNivel : UserControl
        {
           int number;
           String header = "Configuración nivel ";


           public ConfigNivel(int number)
           {
               this.number = number;
               header += Convert.ToString(number);
               InitializeComponent();
           }
        }
```

Con el consiguiente resultado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

cuando se establece el enlace de datos (binding), se busca la propiedad que tenga el mismo nombre en el datacontext
no veo que tengas asignado el datacontext,

Con un patrón mvvm mas o menos seria asi:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding}" Width="200">
<Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Expander.HeaderTemplate>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentLine1}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentLine2}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentLine3}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
public string Title { get; set; }
public string ContentLine1 { get; set; }
public string ContentLine2 { get; set; }
public string ContentLine3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public DemoViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeViewModel();
}

private void InitializeViewModel()
{
    ViewModel = new DemoViewModel
    {
        Title = "Expander Title",
        ContentLine1 = "This is line 1",
        ContentLine2 = "This is line 2",
        ContentLine3 = "This is line 3"
    };
    this.DataContext = ViewModel;
}
}
```

Comment: Lo pruebo esta tarde y te comento.
Igual es una pregunta un poco absurda pero... ¿Cuando recomendarías ponerse al tanto con diseño de patrones? Teniendo en cuenta que todavía estoy empezando con C#... nunca he tenido claro cuando ponerse con cierto "nivel" de aprendizaje, no quiero empezar la casa por el tejado :D

Comment: Patrones desde ya, para evitar grandes clases , código espagueti ,  en presentación patrones mvvm , mvc, etc se usan en todas las tecnologías app en xamarin ,web wpf solo Windows forms usa code behind y hay ciertas formas de evitar eso

Comment: Estoy probando el ejemplo y la parte que me interesa a mi, el Header, no se actualiza de ninguna manera...
Tampoco en mi propio programa, se queda siempre el campo vacio, aunque la variable internamente si que obtiene el valor...

Comment: falta el binding en <Expander Header="{Binding}" Width="200"> lo actualizo